# Android failed to play mp4 files hosted in a password protected directory

Tags: android, html, .htaccess

I am working with a html5 video player in my website using videojs and I found out that the video don't play in Android devices. After few tests and check possible issues over the internet, I found out that the issue is because android cannot access the video as its hosted in a password protected directory. I tried to add mime type in my htaccess but it still wont work. I dont know anything about htaccess so please help me.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have just posted probably the same issue over at [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57189/htaccess-protected-html5-videos-not-playing).

Comment: I solved the issue by changing my video source files somewhere its has no authentications. and that works fine after that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately removing the password protection is not an option here.

Comment: have you tried to supply authentication info in your url? e.g http://username:password@www.website.com/password-protected-folder/track.mp4

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an option since the videos need to be accessible to only a specific circle of people, who got their own logins.

Comment: hmm I see, well in my case I had the same situation too where we, my team, uses out network where we have authentication. It doesnt matter if I provide the authentication at the url, besides only us could access the  video page, and its not even public.

Answer (score 1):

What are the URLs used to load the mp4 files?

You might be able to specify the username and password in the URL:

```
http://username:password@www.website.com/password-protected-folder/track.mp4
```